# Cambiar nombre de archivo con nombre que varía mediante Python

Tags: python, formularios, archivo

Estoy intentando cambiar automáticamente el nombre de un archivo (Una encuesta de Microsoft Forms) cuyo nombre va cambiando cada vez que lo descargo según la cantidad de respuestas que contiene la encuesta (al final del nombre del xlsx aparece ese detalle).

Mi objetivo es detectar el archivo que en su nombre contiene la palabra "Noviembre" (Tengo varios archivos que se llaman similar pero cambia el nombre del mes y la cantidad de respuestas) y mediante un `os.rename` acortar el nombre y quitarle el numero de respuestas.

Esto es lo que llevo del código, mi pregunta es como modificar el directorio de entrada para que se cumpla la condición que menciono arriba.

```
import os
os.rename (r"E:\Usuarios\mtellez.lh\Downloads\PARA VALIDAR TU EVIDENCIA DE GESTIÓN DE NOVIEMBRE CONTESTA LA SIGUIENTE PREGUNTA (OBLIGATORIO)(1-297).xlsx", r"E:\Usuarios\mtellez.lh\Downloads\Evidencia noviembre.xlsx")
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: No entiendo la duda. ¿Qué importa que tenga "Noviembre" en el nombre? Por otro lado, en tu ejemplo tienes dos archivos con diferentes nombres (pues uno pone Encuesta **A** mientras que el otro es **B**, aparte del número entre paréntesis), pero el nombre al que quieres cambiar es uno solo. ¿Quieres juntar ambos archivos en uno? ¿Quieres renombrar sólo uno de ellos? ¿Cuál?

Comment: MoisesT, bienvenido, te sugiero que sigas el [tour] para que veas como funciona el sitio. Te adelanto que la idea es que presentes el avance del código que llevas, y que las consultas que realices, sean puntuales.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas! He reformulado mi pregunta para que se entienda de mejor manera. Basicamente, necesito agregar un condicional al nombre de la direccion de entrada ya que el archivo madre a veces cambia de nombre al final pero la constante es que siempre se mantiene el nombre del mes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal, se trata de buscar en cierta carpeta un fichero que contiene en su nombre la palabra "Noviembre" y renombrarlo.

La implementación hace directamente lo dicho en la frase anterior. Obtiene todos los nombres de fichero en esa carpeta y mira uno a uno si contiene la palabra "noviembre", deteniéndose en el primero que lo cumpla, y cambiándole el nombre a uno fijo. Para hacerlo más flexible, toma de variables el mes y la carpeta.

```
import os


mes = "noviembre"
carpeta = 'E:\\Usuarios\\mtellez.lh\\Downloads\\'
nombre_final = "Evidencia {}.xlsx".format(mes)

for filename in os.listdir(carpeta):
    if mes in filename.lower():
        print("Renombrando {} como {}".format(filename, nombre_final))
        os.rename(carpeta + filename, carpeta + nombre_final)
        break
```

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia! eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba. El único detalle que tuve que modificar es que en el `os.rename`, para realizar la búsqueda de la dirección inicial es necesario colocar la dirección completa y no solo el nombre del arcyhivo, por lo que quedó así:

`os.rename(carpeta + filename, carpeta + nombre_final)`

Comment: Oh, tienes razón. Lo escribí sin testearlo (al no tener esa carpeta...) Lo corrijo para futuros lectores